# Photoshop or mac tool, make image 8bit (PIXELATE)

Tags: image, macos, photoshop, pixelate

Does any one knows some trick for photoshop or has link to some mac osx tool for render images like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29692/create-cool-8-bit-style-pixel-art-from-ordinary-images/) a very good tutorial on how to pixalate images using cool effects in photoshop.

Example:

[image]